# Thirty reopen votes in one day

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

We’re normally limited to 20 reopen votes per day. I was working my way
through the queue today, reached 20, it gave me another one. Okay,
weird, whatever, I kept going. Reached 30. Looked around on Meta to see
if the limit had been increased, saw nothing. Asked on Chat (SO Close
Vote Reviewers), no one knew anything. Went back to “all queues”, Reopen
Votes is grayed out and it thanks me for doing 20 today.

Did the system glitch or something?

Update: per comments, the queue probably exceeded 150 temporarily, which increases votes to 40.

Screenshot from https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats:
[image]

Comment: Was the size of the queue briefly over 1,000? In that case, the review limit per user changes to 40. In that case, it probably dropped below 1000 after you reviewed 30, dropping the limit back to 20, and preventing you from reviewing more.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Didn’t notice, but in my screenshot taken shortly afterwards, it shows 125, so over 1,000 seems unlikely.

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected more people reviewing more than 20. The only other cause I can think of is reviewing one's own post, but that only applies to the suggested edits queue.

Comment: Is the “bug” tag appropriate? The description says “reproducible” and this does not seem to be.

Comment: It's a bug that it let you review more than 20 without the queue size ever crossing 1,000.

Comment: Do you mean "reopen votes" or "reviews in the reopen vote queue"?

Comment: [*When the queue size is greater than 150, you will have 40 reviews a day*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/578411) but when the queue size drops under 150, you're no longer eligible to review 40. If you have done more then 20 already, you're lucky.

Comment: @rene Ah, well, 150. That explains it. Much more plausible than 1,000. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was looking at an older post. It *used* to be 1,000, with 150 in Triage, but it was later changed to 150 in all queues. Sorry for misguiding you.

Comment: Retagging this as [support] – I can't keep up with those changes either.